# Apache http.conf - Route Requests to URL Directory Using Alias

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have a web application that I would like to be accessed in the following format:

```
52.1.2.3/myapplication
```

I currently have a `httpd.conf` that looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public_html
    ServerName 52.1.2.3
    ServerAlias 52.1.2.3
    Alias /myapplication /var/www/myapp/public_html
    <Directory /var/www/myapp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I got to the URL `52.1.2.3/myapplication`, I want Apache to load the application stored in `/var/www/myapp/public_html`.

If I take out the `Alias /myapplication /var/www/mya/pp/public_html` configuration from the above, I can reach my web application by going to `52.1.2.3`.  But when I try to go to `52.1.2.3/myapp` with the `Alias` option added in, I get a 403 Forbidden response.

How would you bind `52.1.2.3/myapplication` to `/var/www/myapp/public_html`?

Comment: And what does the error log say exactly?

Answer (score 0):

in my understanding you have to add the same path to the directory which you have used for the alias.

So,your path for alias /myapplication is /var/www/myapp/public_html.So put the same in below directory :

```
<Directory /var/www/myapp/public_html>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```